# Cómo puedo acceder al servidor mysql instalado manualmente dentro de un docker con Ubuntu

Tags: docker

He instalado una imagen de Ubuntu en un docker con el comando `docker pull Ubuntu`. Dentro de esta imagen he instalado mysql, tanto el servidor como el cliente. Previamente hice update y un upgrade y posteriormente instalé mysql con estos comandos: `apt install mysql-server` y `apt install mysql-client`.

Para entrar en el contenedor previa instalación de mysql sobre Ubuntu lo hice con este comando:

```
docker run -it -p 3306:3306 --name ubuntu-mysql ubuntu bash
```

En ese comando comparto el puerto `3306` del docker con mi local, pero cuando desde fuera del contenedor intento conectar a mysql no me es posible. Me rechaza la conexión.

Soy bastante nuevo con este tema de los contenedores y seguramente algo estoy haciendo mal. Sé que hay imágenes de mysql con todas las herramientas necesarias para trabajar con esta bbdd, pero mi objetivo era instalar mysql dentro de un docker Ubuntu y poder acceder a mysql desde fuera de contenedor. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto, es posible?

Comment: padaleina y gilito, en el fondo agradezco vuestras correcciones, pero si no vais a ofrecer nada más productivo que un absurdo cambio de formato, de corazón os digo que dediquéis vuestro tiempo a otras cosas mucho más sustanciales. El aburrimiento envejece, y luego pasan estas cosas.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el MySQL instalado solo se escucha las llamadas que viene de localhost. Por tanto, hay que cambiar la configuración de MySQL para que se escuche desde fuera.

1. Entras dentro del condenador de MySQL
2. Ir al archivo de configuración de mysql

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
   ```

3)Remplazar `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`   con `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

4. Guardar y reiniciar MySQL server

`sudo systemctl restart mysql`

**Importante**

Vez de instalar MySQL en un Ubuntu, ¿Porqué no descargas una imagen cuál ya tiene MySQL instalado?

```
docker pull ubuntu/mysql
```

Comment: Hola Shamith, sé que puedo instalar una imagen de mysql directamente, pero era por experimentar con los contenedores. Voy a probar lo que me dices y comento a ver qué tal me fue. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Solucionado Shamith, era cuestión de los permisos del usuario. Tuve que crear un usuario en mysql cuyo host fuese '%', por el contrario me daba error de permisos. Ahora ya puedo conectar a MySql desde fuera del contenedor sin problema. Gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: @JoséManuel Sí, también es un punto importante,  me alegro de que hayas podido solucionar. Saludos